# How can I read multiple computer descriptions?

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I want to create a script which reads all the computernames from a CSV file. And from all of these, I want the description. Also it should be exported in a single CSV.

This is what I tried but...

```cs
$path = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 

$path_import_csv = $path + "\" + "Computernamen.csv"
$path_export_csv = $path + "\" + "Alessio.csv"

$computernames = Import-Csv $path_import_csv

foreach ($computername in $computernames) {
    Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=1,OU=2,OU=3,DC=my,DC=domain" -Properties * |
        Select -Expand description |
        Export-Csv -Path $path_export_csv -Append -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Force
}
```

Comment: "But..." what? What did you expect your code to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: The `foreach` loop never uses `$computername`. Is this a copy-paste error or actual feature in the code?

Comment: Your `foreach` loop is not searching for the `$computername`. If you want to do that, then you need `Get-AdComputer $computername`. If `Computernamen.csv` is truly a CSV, then it either already has a header or you need to add one. If it has a header, then `$computernames.header` will be the syntax to access the list. If it doesn't have a header, then just read the file with `Get-Content $path_import_csv`. If you are going to export to CSV, then you need to output an object with properties, i.e. `select -expand description` only outputs description text and needs to become `select description`.

Comment: Please show an example of the import CSV, and what you would like to see in the output CSV.

Comment: Hey Thanks for all the replies! I am really new to powershell and try to learn it :D
The example IMPORT csv
Computernames
Computer1
Computer2
Computer3
...

The example EXPORT csv
Description
Name1
Name2
Name3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment I gather that file `Computernamen.csv` is not a CSV file at all, but just a text file with computer names each on a separate line.
In that case, you do not use `Import-Csv`, but `Get-Content` to retrieve an array of computer names.

Also (others already made that clear) you are not using the `$computername` variable in the foreach loop at all AND by adding the `-ExpandProperty` switch to the `Select-Object` cmdlet, you are not receiving an **object** with property Description, but just the description as string .
For outputting a CSV with `Export-Csv`, you need to have a (series of) objects.

Also, I would recommend using the `Join-Path` cmdlet for creating file paths instead of contatenating string with `+` so you don't have to worry about possible missing backslashes.

Instead of `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition` you can also use the `$PSScriptRoot` variable to get the current script path.
In Windows PowerShell 2.0, this variable is valid only in script modules (.psm1). 
Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, it is valid in all scripts.

```
$path            = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition   # or use $PSScriptRoot
$path_import_csv = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'Computernamen.csv'
$path_export_csv = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'Alessio.csv'
$computernames   = Get-Content $path_import_csv
$searchBase      = 'OU=1,OU=2,OU=3,DC=my,DC=domain'

$result = foreach ($computername in $computernames) {
    # it is bad practice to use -Properties * if all you need is a small set of properties
    $computer = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq '$computername'" -SearchBase $searchBase -Properties Name, Description -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # did we find a computer by that name?
    if ($computer) {
        # output an object with the two selected properties to get collected in the $result variable
        $computer | Select-Object Name, Description
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "A computer with name '$computername' does not exist."
    }
}

# output the result on console
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# save the result as proper CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path $path_export_csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation -Force
```